Manhwa / manhua where the main character and team fight the final boss; the main character sacrifices himself and reincarnates years later
More details: Mc sacrifices himself in a battle against the final boss (not sure what is the boss). He is later reincarnated years after his death, only to find that the world he saved has turned against him and the other heros. People believe his sacrifice was unnecessary and blame him for the hardships they now face.
The heros are now replaced by another team of heros. The old team is discriminated against and hated.
Additional info: MC is in an academy. There are multiple safe zones. In one of the safe zones, he saw his team mates and how badly she was treated. In the same chapter, she recognise him even after he reincarnated

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

I rmb reading it this year ard Jan/Feb but can’t seem to remember the name. It is full colour
